# Google Analytics for direct resource on Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-analytics

I'm working on a site for hosting images, for example: http://i.proxgur.com/kMoI9Vn.jpg. The images are handled through Node.js with the following:

```
// Check if image exists in cache
if (fs.existsSync('cache/' + req.params.image)) {
    log("File exists in cache, streaming from /cache/" + req.params.image, 'INFO', ip);

    // Read image from cache
    fs.createReadStream('cache/' + req.params.image).pipe(res);
} else {
    log("File does not exist, streaming from http://i.imgur.com/" + req.params.image, 'WARN', ip);

    // Pipe from Imgur to user
    request(url).pipe(res);

    log("Saving file to cache", 'INFO', ip);

    // Pipe from Imgur to cache
    request(url).pipe(fs.createWriteStream('cache/' + req.params.image));
}
```

I use GA for the homepage, album pages and more, however I would like to be able to collect analytics for images accessed directly. Is there anyway I can invoke GA without adding the code to the response?

Comment: Tthere are node modules implementing the measurement protocol that do not need to send output to the browser (e.g. https://www.npmjs.org/package/universal-analytics) - tracking can be done serverside. Haven't tested myself but might be worth looking at.